# Can two 12v power supplies be connected together to increase the amperage power

Tags: power-supply, power

I have two 12v 30amp power supplies and I would like to know if I could connect them together to get an output of 12v 60 amps of power

Comment: It depends on what power supplies they are. In general, no, but if they are meant to be paralleled, then yes. We don't know what kind of power supplies you have, so we can't answer this. Do you have a manual?

Comment: If the second supply happens to output 12.1V and first one 12V (say, due to small variations in the components), then connecting their output terminals *directly* together can cause current to flow from the second supply **into** the first. If there is no element in the supply's circuit to *limit* this current to safe levels, it can damage both supplies.

Comment: Given slightly unequal voltages, and enough load (>30A) you may find one PSU in current limit (30A) while the other makes up the remainder. If the PSU has foldback instead of current limit, this won't work at all; hence it depends on whether the PSU is designed for this use.

Comment: The power supply is 1 of those 12v 30amp computer power supplies

Comment: 12V 30A 360W Switching Power Supply Adapter, this is what the power supply is called if checked on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Two identical linear regulated power supplies may be paralleled, *should there be a facility to do so.*

There are linear regulated power supply models which have the facility to interlink the regulated drive fed to the driver transistors in two identical supplies.

Paralleling them would involve the following:

1. Adjusting the output voltage of each supply to within 10 mV DC.
2. Paralleling the output terminals.
3. Interconnecting the regulated drive terminals.

It goes without saying that both the power supplies are to be kept powered off, while carrying out the interconnection as per steps 2 & 3 above.